# Как найти ближайший элемент из vector'а по расстоянию в 2D?

Tags: c++

Есть игрок. Вокруг него есть тоже игроки, к примеру, 10 (их может быть и 100)

Нужно найти указатель самого ближайшего на него. Пытался сделать так:

```
// создаем массив, в котором будут содержаться массивы с игроками
vector <vector<int>> Buffer_Vectors_Players;

// создаем массив, в котором будет содержаться указатель на конкретного игрока и дистанция до него
vector<int> BufferPlayerWithDistance;

// заполняем массив

for (int i = 1; i < CountPlayers; i++)
{
        int pPlayer = bla-bla-bla

        // дистанция от текущего игрока до обнаруженного 
        distance_to_player = bla-bla-bla


        // заполняем массив конкретного игрока указателем на него и дистанцией до него (дистанция от текущего)
        BufferPlayerWithDistance.push_back(pPlayer);
        BufferPlayerWithDistance.push_back(distance);

    // заполняем общий массив с игроками массивом с указателем на игрока и дистанцией до него   Buffer_Vectors_Players.push_back(BufferPlayerWithDistance);
// чистим массив с конкретным игроком, чтобы перейти к следующему


        BufferPlayerWithDistance.clear();

}
```

Comment: Вы минимум в массиве искать умеете? Здесь то же самое.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На вскидку:

```
struct Player
{
    int x, y;
};

Player target_player = ...; // Игрок, к которому ищем ближайшего.
std::vector<Player> player_list = {...}; // Список остальных игроков.

Player *nearest_player = 0; // Указатель на ближайшего игрока
int min_distance_sqr = -1; // Квадрат расстояния до него (чтобы каждый раз не считать корень)
for (Player &player : player_list)
{
    int delta_x = player.x - target_player.x;
    int delta_y = player.y - target_player.y;
    int distance_sqr = delta_x*delta_x + delta_y*delta_y;
    if (min_distance_sqr > distance_sqr)
    {
        min_distance_sqr = distance_sqr;
        nearest_player = &player;
    }
}
```